# Unable to trigger an elementor popup on mousover

Tags: jquery

I created a vertical style menu using popups in elementor and I want to enable submenu popups on hover. I tried this code for one of the buttons on my popup but I keep getting an error - "unexpected <". Please see code below. (the button has a class - aboutpop assigned to it). Thanks.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".aboutpop").mouseover(function(){
         elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( {id:25261}, event);
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Click on the error message to see where exactly is the error in your code, then fix it or post it here

Answer (score 0):

Please do not bother. I realised my error. I did not put the approriate tags at the beginning of the code and at the end.

I've corrected this now and the code is working just fine.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  jQuery(function($){
    $('.aboutpop').on('mouseenter', function() {
    elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: 25261 } );
    });
  });
});
</script>
<?php } );
```